# CSS display changes after changing zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

I am having a little bit of trouble with my CSS, as when I change the default zoom (Command + on Mac) of the browser it causes the below image. [image]

When it is at 100% viewport on chrome, it is supposed to look like the below where it fits perfectly in the black box.
[image]

My html code is below. For the sake of simplicity, I have only included the container and the  tag to show where I wrote it.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-bars"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS code is below:

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(89, 87, 87);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

.container {
  background-color: rgb(37, 35, 35);
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  left: 500px;
  top: 150px;
}

.bars {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid rgb(232, 10, 10);
  background-color: rgb(218, 215, 215);
}
```

The .container is the black box in the background and the body is the grey background. Finally, .bars just represents the CSS for each bar. I am creating a visualizer so the when adding the bars, I am using javascript. The code for adding the bars is below.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

function add_bars(input) {
    const Div = document.createElement('div');
    const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
    const containerHeight = container.clientHeight;
    const barWidth = containerWidth / inputval - 2;
    Div.className = 'bars';
    //prettier-ignore
    Div.style.height = `${((containerHeight / 100) * input) - 2}px`;
    Div.style.width = `${barWidth}px`;
    containerBars.append(Div);
}
```

The input in this case is how large the size of the array is which I am dividing in order to split the width of each bar equally. Any help would be appreciated as to why it exceeds the container when I change how "zoomed" in the browser is. Thanks!

```
function for_loop(array) {
    resetArray();
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        add_bars(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of inputVal in line 4 of add_bars function? and what is the value of input when you call add_bars?

Comment: Hi, 

So inputval corresponds to the value I have to manually enter for how big the array is. So in the picture provided, it is 50. 

As for input, I have a button that generates a random array so the value input varies from either 1-100 since it is random. Add-bars is more so a helper function that is at the bottom of my post (easier to read). The size of the array is the inputval. Now looking back, I could technically just loop over the range of inputval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `%` or `vh` `vw` in css and change zoom the elements will change their sizes. Try a console.log(document.querySelector(".container")) after and before changing zoom and you will see a different value. In order to avoid that behavior you have to use fixed sizes in your elements. For example:

```
.container {
  background-color: rgb(37, 35, 35);
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px; // pixels, not % or vh
  width: 800px;// the same
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

Also, when you make zoom out the problem persist. In order to avoid that just add the next:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And there is no need to substract 2 px in add_bars function:

```
...
const barWidth = containerWidth / inputval;
...
Div.style.height = `${((containerHeight / 100) * input)}px`;
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I think that fixes it. Although, I was wondering, if I keep zooming smaller, eventually the bars won't be able to fit into the black box. For example at 70% zoom. Could you explain why that is?

Comment: That is because of border of the bars. In order to fix that problem you only have to add box-sizing: border-box; to all elements. And not substract 2 px to width and heigh in add_bar function. I will edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That's exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't piece it into words

Comment: You are welcome! It would be greate if you vote that my answer was usefull :)

Comment: Okay, you answered my questions perfectly :D